# Twilio Call Logs (Node.js helper Library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am just trying to get a list of all calls from a specific number with the twilio-node helper library, but currently I have some issues with the async behaviour of the function to retrieve the call logs.

So my code looks like this:

```js
const filter = {
   from: phoneNumber
};

var calls = {};

client.calls
.each(filter, call => {
  calls[call.sid] = call;
});
```

So what I am trying to do, is to wait for all calls to be fetched and inserted into the calls object. After that has been completed, I need to call a function that returns the call object. I already tried .then(() => {}); and .done(() => {}); but that keeps giving me the following error:

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I hope someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`client.calls.each` is intended to be used to deal with each call as they are received from the API. If you want a list of calls then you can use the `list` method. Be sure to set a `limit` though, as `list` by default will fetch *all* calls.

```
const filter = {
  from: phoneNumber,
  limit: 50
};

client.calls.list(filter).then(calls => { // do something with all the calls });
```

Let me know if that helps.